# Is it ok to have overloaded operators throw Errors in Python?

Tags: python

I am working on a research project. I wrote a class called point has overloaded comparison operators (<, >, <=, and <=). I also have another class called reflection which performs certain operations on points. However, there will be times in which a Reflection will return a point which cannot be compared. Here is an outline of the code I am working with.

```
class Point:
    def init__(self, values):
        self.values = values
        self.definite = True

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if not self.definite or not other.definite:
            raise ValueError("Points are not Definite!")
        # Implementation details

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not self.definite or not other.definite:
            raise ValueError("Points are not Definite!")
        # Implementation details


    def makeDefinite(self):
        # Add code to give the point definite values.
        self.definite = True
        return

class Reflection:
    def __init__(self, i, j):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j

    def execute(self, point):
        # This method performs the designated reflection to the point. If j = 0, the point becomes indefinite
        if self.j == 0:
            point.definite = False
        #  Implementation details
```

Is it ok for me to raise errors like this? If not, how can I achieve the same functionality without raising errors? It is important to note that the makeDefinite method can only be called at certain times.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: `'1' > 1` raises a `TypeError`, so not only is it OK, Python already does it for `str.__gt__()`. This question is better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MichaelRuth I would class the question as a GBP an close the question on Code Review.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I'm sorry I'm pretty new to this. Would you mind explaining how I can move this question to code review?

Comment: As I mentioned before, if you migrate your question to Code Review your question will be closed. You currently have no close votes on SO so as a non-SO user I would suggest staying on SO.

Comment: @Peilonrayz What does "GBP" mean?

Comment: @Peilonrayz Okay, thanks, I just couldn't find the acronym anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is normal to raise exceptions when implementing numeric types. It's usually best to match the actions of the standard types. For instance `1/0` raises `ZeroDivisionError` and if there is a similar case in your class, that same thing should be raised.

That's "usually". You may want the semantics of these operators to behave differently. For instance in `pathlib.Path`, division is actually a join of subpaths.

There is one caveat of note. In [Emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=emulating#emulating-numeric-types), it is suggested that one `return NotImplemented` when the type of one operator doesn't support the operation. This is because Python may try multiple operator method calls to get an operation to work - it may be that `int` doesn't understand your class but your class understands `int`. So a reverse operation may work. If all attempts fail, Python then raises a `TypeError` for you.